# RestSharp returning HTML

Tags: restsharp

I have created an app that uses RestSharp to interact with a REST API.

The same exact code that run perfectly well on my PC, returns HTML on another PC.

Things I have done:

I have checked the NuGet versions of all packages and they are the same.
I have checked the .NET version to make sure they are the same.

The code looks like this but definitely two different responses.

```
        var request = new RestRequest();
        var client = new RestClient();

        client = new RestClient(URL);
        client.Timeout = -1;
        request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        response = client.Execute(request);
```

Thank you in advanced for any insight you might have.